# How to repeat axes setting in a loop in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, settings, axes

I usually use the following commands to create a multi-panel plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, mainax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100)
ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4 = mainax.flatten()
```

Then, I use the following command to adjust the axes setting:

```
ax1.tick_params('x', which='major', length=10, width=2, direction='in', labelsize=24, labelbottom=True)

ax1.tick_params('x', which='minor', length=7, width=2, direction='in')

for axis in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax1.spines[axis].set_linewidth(2)

for tick in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_fontname('serif')
```

I have to repeat them for `ax1`, `ax2`, `ax3`, and `ax4`. As long as I have a few panels, there is no problem, but when I have too many panels (e.g., 5 rows and 4 columns) the code would be ugly if I repeat them.

How can I put them in a loop?
Or any alternative way to avoid repeating the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid any loop by using [**`matplotlib.rcParams`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rcParams).
You can add those line at the beginning of your python script:

```
rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 10
rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 2
rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 24
rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True

rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 7
rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 2

rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'

rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2
```

Refer to [this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) for more customization options.
Example of working code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 10
rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 2
rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 24
rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True

rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 7
rcParams['xtick.minor.width'] = 2

rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'

rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2


fig, mainax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10), dpi=100)

plt.show()
```

- 2 rows and 2 columns:

  [image]
- 5 rows and 4 columns:

  [image]

Comment: And any idea what is the key for tick label rotation?

for tick in ax1.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(30)

Comment: As far as I know, the tick label rotation is not considered a _style_ parameter, so you do not find any key for that in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html). I think that, for this parameter, you should iterate over all axes